# Color fields in XPages

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have been working on a database in Lotus Domino Designer 8.5, specifically with XPages.  I've noticed that I can include a field on a FORM as a color field, with a color picker, but the same functionality is not available within XPages.  Basically, the person populating the document would pick a color (Green, Yellow, Red, or Blue), and I would like the field to show that color block.  I am fairly new to Domino Designer, so I don't know if I'm missing something or some coding technique, but any advice or guidance would be helpful.

Comment: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/widget/ColorPicker.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this in an XPages "spreadsheet". Take a look at my blog article at http://www.teamspace.ca/TeamSpace/Blog.nsf/dx/using-xpages-to-develop-complex-reports-part-2.htm

Comment: That actually explains exactly what I was going for... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use new HTML5 input `type` of [`color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html#input.color.attrs.type).

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" type="color"></xp:inputText>
```

**Note:** It does not work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: "does not work in Internet Explorer" == cool feature I can't use lol. Seriously cool tip though!

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at CSS.

You should create a stylesheet and then add that style sheet to the page as a resource. Then you simply apply that style to your resource. So you would set in the stylesheet how you want fields to look if they are black. Then you apply that style to any fields you want to have the same color. This allows you to change all fields at the same time by simply modifying the stylesheet, or having styles computed easily.

I will see if I can dig up some code for you.

I would stay away from the individual styling that Domino designer uses.

Comment: Is it possible to code it so if the user picks a color (say from a drop down menu) or enters a certain value ("red") that the field will be that color? In short, the color of the field is dependent upon the input.

Comment: Yes. Define all of your styles, then use a bit a js to define the style, then do a partial refresh on the area to dynamically load the correct style.

Answer (score 1):

I did sth like this in an application using XPages and I used this one:

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Very easy to implement to a editbox control on an XPage.